# How to clear search and command history in Vim?

Tags: vim

If you search something in Vim by prepending searchterm with a forward slash, e.g. `/searchterm`, Vim puts that searchterm into the *search string history table*. You then are able to navigate through past search terms by typing in forward slash (`/`) and using <kbd>Up</kbd>/<kbd>Down</kbd> arrow keys.

That search string history table is persistent across Vim restarts.

Everything above is also true for command (typed with `:` prepended) history table.

How do I clear those history tables?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The history is persisted in the *viminfo* file; you can configure what (and how many of them) is persisted via the `'viminfo'` (and `'history'`) options.

You can clear the history via the `histdel()` function, e.g. for searches:

```
:call histdel('/')
```

You can even delete just certain history ranges or matching lines.

Alternatively, you could also just edit the `~/.viminfo` file directly (when Vim is closed, and either with another editor, or with `vim -i NONE`).

Comment: `:call histdel(":")` deletes the entire command history. Use `:call histdel(":", "expr")` to delete entries matching an expression.

Comment: `:call histdel('/', -1)` deletes last search

Answer (score 0):

Edit `~/.viminfo` go to section `# Search String History` and remove the lines that you whish to not appear to search history. Unlike `histdel()` these changes are permanent.

Comment: If you use vim to edit `~/.viminfo` directly, you may want to page through the file and search for offending strings visually. Because, any `/` search you do will just end up going back into the file.